# GLPaint - Save image as vector image

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am using CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB() which returns a png image(pixel format)? Is there a way to save this image as a vector image. Basically I need to save the pictures drawn by the GLPaint application as a vector image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about this function or about GLPaint, but you can't take a pixellized image and turn it into a vector image. Only humans and highly clever algorithms can do that ( see http://vectormagic.com/ )

If you have access to the input (gestures?) of GLPaint, you should convert them to SVG directly instead of passing through an RGB image.

Comment: Also I presume, that GLPaint uses OpenGL. OpenGL is a rasterizing drawing API, so what you get will always be a pixel image. There is an extension called "transform feedback", but this only returns the transformed vertices. No depth testing, no fragment shader magic, etc.